# in my project the control goes to http to https but in http i put the values in session but the control goes http the values are null

Tags: google-app-engine

I am working with `googleapp`. In my project I fetch the connections from LinkedIn. It works fine locally, but when I deploy the `googleappengine` it does not work. My control goes from http to https(LinkedIn Login Page ) and at that time my session values are null please help me.

```
            OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
        .provider(LinkedInApi.class)
         .apiKey("ln835u1zgg0c")
         .apiSecret("I9Bz3lloYT8jlO6P").scope("r_network")
          .callback("http://mygbuddy.appspot.com/CallBackUrl.jsp")
           .build();


        Token requestToken=service.getRequestToken();
        HttpSession session=request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("service", service);
        session.setAttribute("requesttoken", requestToken);


              CallBackUrl.jsp
            <%
                  out.println(session.getAttribute("service"););


                 %>
```

in jsp i got null please help me

Answer (score 0):

GAE is a distributed system. So your request can be processed on any of multiple instance started. Common session data between different instances is done using DataStore persistence. 
When you put something to session it is actually stored in DataStore. It means that atrributes should follow DataStore persistent requirements ( https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities ).

Standard OAUthServiceImpl GAE class is not serializable (check http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/oauth/OAuthServiceImpl.java?r=194) so it can not be stored in DataStore and accessed later.

Comment: thanks for the replay but now how to over come this please help me

Comment: You should not store Service in session. Store just some strings or something that will identify user and could be serializable. Environment should be created/read on every request.

Comment: ok..i am put some value in session than i want the service and token objects to my Displayconnections.jsp page how can i get...and i use context scope to store those values but in my project at a time acess the linkedin two user the application scope values are overridden means one person allow acess second person got error message ..how to overcome this..if u have any sample code please help me..thanks for the replay

Comment: hello please help me..i am struck here since 3days

Comment: As I wrote - this approach will not work for GAE. You should create an OAuth service every time you need it. You can try to create it using static field on instance start. There is no way to keep Service or Token during session. It is a nature of High-load distributed systems. You can not use all J2EE patterns.

Comment: hi thanks for the replay in my project i want to update the user profiles for google app https://developers.google.com/google-apps/profiles/ every thing is ok but in my project some times need custom fields for the user how to create the cutsom fields for the user please help me

Comment: I think it will be better to do a separate question. I did not work with profiles much, so can not help you quickly.